# Balls complete in metric space

Tags: real-analysis

I'm struggling with the following task, i'd be thankful if anybody could help me out with a solution.

Note $ (X,d)= (\mathbb{R}^n,d) $, $ \  R= S^{n-1}(0)= \{  x \in \mathbb{R}^n $: $ \ |x|=1 $} and $z  \in $ R.

Then: $$ B_e(z)= \{x \in R: \ d_R(x,z)< \varepsilon \ \} \  \text{is complete in} \  (R,d_R) \leftrightarrow \varepsilon > 2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $R$ is compact, hence complete. A subset of a complete metric space is complete if and only if it is closed.

---

Assembling the gist of the argument from the comments to have a self-contained complete answer after it has been solved:

The boundary of the open ball $B_\varepsilon(z)$ is the set $S_\varepsilon(z) = \{ x \in R: d_R(x,y) = \varepsilon\}$. Since $R$ is complete, the open ball is complete if and only if it is closed, and that is the case if and only if $S_\varepsilon(z) = \varnothing$. Since the diameter of $R$ is $2$, we have $B_\varepsilon(z) = R$ for $\varepsilon >2$, hence $B_\varepsilon(z)$ is complete for $\varepsilon > 2$. For $0 < \varepsilon \leqslant 2$, there are points in $R$ with $d_R(x,z) = \varepsilon$, hence then $S_\varepsilon(z) \neq \varnothing \iff \overline{B_\varepsilon(z)} \neq B_\varepsilon(z)$, so the ball is not closed, hence not complete for $0 < \varepsilon \leqslant 2$.

Comment: To be honest I don't know how this helps me out...

Comment: You need to see when $B_\varepsilon(z)$ is closed. What can you say about the set $\{ y : d_R(y,z) = \varepsilon\}$?

Comment: This would be a closed set, because there are y, where $B_e(y) \notin$ set, right?

Comment: Now it's my turn to not know what you're getting at. What I was getting at is "what is the relation between $B_\varepsilon(z)$ and $\{y : d_R(y,z) = \varepsilon\}$?"

Comment: $ \{y: d_R (y,z) = \varepsilon \} $ are the limit points of $B_e(z)$ which are not in $B_e(z)$?

Comment: Usually. The exception is when?

Comment: When $B_e(z)$ is complete?

Comment: Well, yes, but we kind of walk in circles if we take that. Let's try a bit differently. What's $\overline{B_\varepsilon(z)}$?

Comment: All points y, where $ d(y,z) \leq \varepsilon $?

Comment: Right. And $B_\varepsilon(z)$ is closed if and only if $B_\varepsilon(z) = \overline{B_\varepsilon(z)}$. So if and only if $\{ y : d_R(y,z) = \varepsilon\} = \varnothing$. And that is the case if - what?

Comment: if $ \varepsilon $ >2, because $y,z \in R$?

Comment: Well, yes, but what property of $R$ makes that happen?

Comment: |x|=1 for all $x \in R$?

Comment: What values can $d_R(y,z)$ have hence?

Comment: Only values $ \leq 2$?

Comment: Yes. But that alone doesn't show that $B_\varepsilon(z)$ is not closed/complete for any $\varepsilon \leqslant 2$. For that we need the full range of values.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for. The range of values x is $0 \leq x \leq 2$, isn't it?

Comment: Right. And that's the point. When $0<\varepsilon\leqslant2$, then there is always at least one point with distance exactly $\varepsilon$, and that is a point in $\overline{B_\varepsilon(z)}\setminus B_\varepsilon(z)$, so then $B_\varepsilon(z)$ is not closed, hence not complete. If $\varepsilon>2$, on the other hand, then $B_\varepsilon(z)=R$ is the entire sphere, which is compact, and hence complete. If there were a $0<\delta\leqslant2$ that did not occur as a value of $d_R$, then $B_\delta(z)$ would also be closed.

Comment: I see, you helped me out alot. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: You're welcome.